# 404 from https://safe-transaction.rinkeby.staging.gnosisdev.com/api/v1/data-decoder/

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-apps-sdk

When I try to run a transaction the gas prediction is not working. In the console I can see that it is from failed call (404) from this interface: https://safe-transaction.rinkeby.staging.gnosisdev.com/api/v1/data-decoder/

This is my transaction snippet:

```
const txs: Transaction[] = [{
                    to: address,
                    value: 0,
                    data: loanContractInterface.encodeFunctionData("functionName",
                    [
                    ethers.utils.formatBytes32String(pickedValue),
                    amount.toString(),
                    safe.safeAddress,
                    ethers.utils.formatBytes32String(buyer),
                    ethers.utils.formatBytes32String(good),
                    Math.floor(dueDate.getTime()/1000)
                ]),
            }];

const params = {
                safeTxGas: 100000,
            };
            
        try {
            const txHash = (await sdk.txs.send({ txs, params })).safeTxHash;
}
```

I am running safe-react and the app locally. The version of safe-react is 3.15.6.

Does somebody have an idea where this problem is likely comming from?
It used to work like this and all of a sudden stopped working. Do I need to upgrade something?

Thanks for the help!
Pascal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The`/api/v1/data-decoder/` is to decode the transaction data before confirming/submitting the transaction. As you use a custom function (e.g. `functionName`) the service does not have an abi for this, therefore it returns a `404`.

To estimate the gas the `/safes/{address}/multisig-transactions/estimations/` is used. For newer Safe versions this endpoint is not used, as the gas will only estimated on transaction execution. (see the docs about `safeTxGas`: https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/main/docs/safe_tx_gas.md)

If your transaction reverts it is also not possible to estimate the required gas. If you want to simulate the transaction I would recommend to use [Tenderly](https://tenderly.co)